# Finding jump probabilities from mean-occupancy values for positions on a one-dimensional random walk

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus

Please imagine a discrete random walk on a one-dimensional lattice.  The lattice consists of a set of $L$ positions, $(x_0, x_1, ..., x_L) \in L$, where $x_0$ is the initial position of the walk (as well as a reflecting boundary), and $x_L$ is absorbing.

For each position in the walk, one of $N$ jump probabilities ($N \leq L$) is assigned (forward - $p_k$, backward - $(1-p_k)$) from a set $P$, where $(p_1, p_2, ..., p_N) \in P$.  However, we do not have knowledge about these assignments.  All we are provided with is a set $M$, $(m_1, m_2, ..., m_L) \in M$, of mean occupancy values for each position in the one-dimensional lattice, $(x_0, x_1, ..., x_L) \in L$.

Now, provided access to $M$, to what extent can we find the values for the set of jump probabilities, $(p_1, p_2, ..., p_N) \in P$ (as defined above), for each position in the lattice, $x_k$?  Can we guarantee a unique solution by placing certain restrictions on the finite set of jump probabilities $P$?

---

(Note - This is the reverse formulation of an earlier question I asked about computing mean occupancy for sites in the one-dimensional random walk from assigned jump probabilities.  See below for the earlier question.)

---

Please imagine a discrete random walk on a one-dimensional lattice.  The lattice consists of a set of $L$ positions, $(x_0, x_1, ..., x_L) \in L$, where $x_0$ is the initial position of the walk (as well as a reflecting boundary), and $x_L$ is absorbing.

For each position in the walk, we assign one of $N$ jump probabilities (forward, $p_k$, backward, $(1-p_k)$) from a set $P$, where $(p_1, p_2, ..., p_N) \in P$.

For the duration of the random walk, until the absorbing target $x_L$ is reached, what is the mean occupancy of the a given position in the one-dimensional lattice, $x_k$?  I'm hoping to find an efficient method to compute an exact solution.

Comment: Is the measure on $P$ uniform?

Comment: If so, consider a given assignment of elements of $P$. The concomitant transition matrix can be constructed straightforwardly (including a "coffin state") and the associated fundamental matrix as well ( http://books.google.com/books?id=0bTK5uWzbYwC&pg=PA75&dq=fundamental+matrix+markov&hl=en&ei=7goITKCfJYKdlgeo_q2RDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=fundamental%20matrix&f=false ). This will give you the information you need for that particular assignment. Then average over the assignments from $P$.

Comment: Steve, thank you, I appreciate the link.  I suppose my question though was - given a 'particular' random assignment of jump probabilities, can one do better than averaging over all the assignments from P to find the mean occupancy for a position $x_k$?  Aside from the contribution of a particular initialization state, my intuition was that the mean occupancy would not be the same for all sites.

Comment: Dear Steve,  I updated my question to reflect my previous comment.  Perhaps it will make a difference?  My apologies for that.

Comment: If you have occupancy times of a birth n' death process until hitting some particular state they are geometric, and if you put the process in continuous time they are exponential, and I think you can relate even joint occupancies to values of bessel processes via imbedding them in brownian motion & using something like a Ray-Knight theorem.